# Update SQL Server table columns with button click from gridview fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview that displays all the fields from my table.

My problem is that I need to update my SQL Server table when I click the save button (onclick) because I added a new field that generates a unique ID to every Item I have in my table. And It will add the generated id to the database table whenever I click the save button.

I have tried this

```
try
{
    strSql = "UPDATE [dbo].[PRDetails] SET [buyerid] = '" + txtBuyerID.Text + 
    "' ,  [prno], [itemaname], [specification], [qty], [uomid], [expenseid], 
    [statusid], [userid], [inserteddate], [withquotation], [potempid] WHERE 
    idnum = '" + pridnum + "'";

    SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand();
    UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, ConnString);

    ConnString.Open();
    UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ConnString.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

But I get an error

Here is my complete code:

```
public void SaveTogrdPOTemp()
{
        SqlConnection ConnString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MUCS2.0ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string strSql = string.Empty;
        pextid = "TPID";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM GenIDGen WHERE extid = '" + pextid + "'"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = ConnString;

            ConnString.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                var extid = sdr["extid"].ToString().Trim();
                var genID = sdr["generatedid"].ToString().Trim();
                var gentr = sdr["generator"].ToString();
                var potempoid = extid + genID;

                ConnString.Close();
            }
        }
        
        strSql = "UPDATE [dbo].[GenIDGen] SET [generator] = generator + 1  
                  WHERE extid = '" + pextid + "'  ";

        SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand();
        UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, ConnString);

        ConnString.Open();
        UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ConnString.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        strSql = "UPDATE [dbo].[PRDetails] SET [buyerid] = '" + txtBuyerID.Text + "' WHERE idnum = '" + pridnum + "'";

        SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand();
        UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql, ConnString);

        ConnString.Open();
        UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ConnString.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

For the generating of ID and the updating of the gridview. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Marceline, can you attach what error you face in the question? And please format your code as there is an indentation issue and it's hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I don't get it, your update text on the code that you say you get an error is wrong, but the last part, that seems to be updating the same table, PRDetails, is right. Also, @marc_s, classic!!! Read about sql Injection https://www.troyhunt.com/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save/

Comment: Use parameters, and also dispose your connection with `using`. It's unclear what the point of the first `select *` is, you don't seem to be doing anything with the result, and if you were, you could probably just do it in a joined update

Comment: Hi Thanks but I already have resolved my issue!